# Issue's to saving data on database, using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Newbie question here: 
I can't save data on firebase App. Why?
I'm using Base64Custom to code user's email, but isn't save. I've already done this a time ago but now it's now working.

1. ```js
   package com.example.eefad.aplicaoteste.activity.Activity;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Base64;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.example.eefad.aplicaoteste.R;
   import com.example.eefad.aplicaoteste.activity.Config.ConfiguracaoFirebase;
   import com.example.eefad.aplicaoteste.activity.helper.Base64Custom;
   import com.example.eefad.aplicaoteste.activity.model.Usuario;
   import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
   import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
   import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
   import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
   import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException;
   import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException;
   import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException;

   ;


   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       private EditText campoNome, campoEmail, campoSenha;
       private Button botaoCadastrar;
       private Usuario usuario;
       private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;


       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           campoNome = findViewById(R.id.editNome);
           campoEmail = findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
           campoSenha = findViewById(R.id.editSenha);
           botaoCadastrar = findViewById(R.id.buttonCadastrar);

           botaoCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {

                   String textoNome = campoNome.getText().toString();
                   String textoEmail = campoEmail.getText().toString();
                   String textoSenha = campoSenha.getText().toString();

                   //Validação do preenchimento dos campos.

                   if(!textoNome.isEmpty() ) {
                       if(!textoEmail.isEmpty()){
                           if(!textoSenha.isEmpty()){
                               usuario = new Usuario();
                               usuario.setNome(textoNome);
                               usuario.setEmail(textoEmail);
                               usuario.setSenha(textoSenha);
                               cadastrarUsuario();



                           }
                       }
                   }


               }
           });


   }
       public void cadastrarUsuario(){
           autenticacao = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
           autenticacao.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getSenha())
                   .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener <AuthResult>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                           if(task.isSuccessful() ){

                            // String idUsuario = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(usuario.getEmail());
                               String idUsuario = usuario.getEmail();
                             usuario.setIdUsuario(idUsuario);
                             usuario.salvar();
                              verificaUsuarioLogado();

                                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Usuário Salvo com Sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               finish();


                           }else {

                               String excecao = "";
                               try {
                                   throw task.getException();
                               }catch ( FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e){
                                   excecao = "Digite uma senha mais forte!";
                               }catch ( FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e){
                                   excecao= "Por favor, digite um e-mail válido";
                               }catch ( FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e){
                                   excecao = "Este conta já foi cadastrada";
                               }catch (Exception e){
                                   excecao = "Erro ao cadastrar usuário: "  + e.getMessage();
                                   e.printStackTrace();
                               }

                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, excecao, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                           }

                       }
                   });



       }


      public void verificaUsuarioLogado(){
           autenticacao =  ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
           if(autenticacao.getCurrentUser() !=null ) {
               startActivity(new Intent(this, TelaCadastro.class));
           }

      }


   }
   ```

I'm using Getters and setter to return data, and i've created a method call salvar to save on database .

```js
package com.example.eefad.aplicaoteste.activity.model;

import com.example.eefad.aplicaoteste.activity.Config.ConfiguracaoFirebase;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;

public class Usuario {

    private String idUsuario;
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String senha;

    public Usuario() {

    }

    public void salvar(){
        DatabaseReference firebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
        firebase.child("usuarios")
                .child(this.idUsuario)
                .setValue(this);



    }

    @Exclude
    public String getIdUsuario() {
        return idUsuario;
    }

    public void setIdUsuario(String idUsuario) {
        this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong. I've was trying to save the email but seems impossible using that structure.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The data insn't save on Firebase. nothing happens.

Comment: So you are not able to see any user data, even under the Authentication option in the Firebase console?

Comment: Solved! The whole problem was with the rules to Read and Write data on Database Console.

Comment: The data was saved in Authentication, but i was wannable to record data on Realtime Database. 
Sorry for the stupid question!